# Validation for file type

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Am using Carrierwave gem to upload the file.

I need to validate the file while uploading ,it should accept only pdf,jpg and png.

Is there solution to do clientside validation.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML input element has an accept attribute you can use to filter by file type. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp

You can also validate by file extension using something like http://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/

This does not prevent a malicious user from uploading a different file type than intended, so you should still validate it after uploading using something like https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/processing/mime_types.rb